# How to print sql or pl/sql with their bind variables using oracledb node js

Tags: node.js, oracle

Is it possible to print generated sql or pl/sql with their bind variables, espescially BIND_IN on pl/sql execution?

for example:

```
select * from departement where id = :idbindid;
```

result: `select * from departement where id = 3`